# vpn has no internet after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, internet, vpn, iptables, pptp

Resently,i upgrade my ubuntu 16.04 server to 18.04

but after upgrading ,my (Cisco anyconnect,pptp) vpn servers  have no internet access...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding following 2 iptables rules to my ubuntu server

```
 iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
 iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

my exisisting iptables rules (related to pptp and ocsrv) before above changes:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens32 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -s 182.18.0.0/24 -j TCPMSS  --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens32 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```